# Try catch block stopping variable declaration

Tags: javascript, xml

I am writing code that is trying to obtain a path value from an XML file and if that path is not found then just set it to blank.

For whatever reason when I try to use the try/catch blocks it errors and says that it can not find the "path". But if I take the try/catch out then it finds it just fine. Is there something special about try/catch that I am missing?

Also of note is that I am try to use try/catch because when I try to set my code variable, if it can not find the path it just errors. I need a way to make it so that if it cannot find the path then it just goes blank and continues on.

Thanks for any tips!

```
for (i = 0; i<listLength; i++){ 
    var path = msg['section']['organizer']['site'][i]['section']['code']['@code'].toString()

    if (path == "1234-5"){

        for (x = 0; x<count; x++){
            try{
                var code = msg['component']['structuredBody']['component']['section']['entry'][x]['act']['entryRelationship'][0]['observation']['participant']['participantRole']['playingEntity']['code']['@code'].toString()
            }
            catch(err){
                code = ""
            }
```

Comment: move for `(x = 0; x<count; x++){` within try block

Comment: @sanjeevRm when I do that I am getting a syntax error..? Care to post an answer with the example?

Comment: declare code outside the try catch

Comment: @epascarello the issue when I do that is that all of the XML files I am feeding in to this are not the same. So if one doesn't find the path for code then it is going to error and die. I need something that will allow me to implement multiple paths so i was thinking the try/catch could do that

Answer (score 0):

Define code outside the try catch so the variable.

```
var code;
try {
  code = mgs...;
} catch () {
  code = '';
}
```

Other option is to not use a try catch, but look up the property in a loop. Something like the  following

```js
function getValue(obj, prop) {
  var keys = prop.split(".");
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (!acc) return acc;
    return acc[key];
  }, obj);
}


var obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: [{
        d: 42
      }]
    }
  }
};

console.log(getValue(obj, "a.b.c.0.d"))
```